# Wi-Fi is not working for Ubuntu 12.04 (Precise Pangolin)

Tags: wireless

Wi-Fi is not working for my Ubuntu installed on Windows 7. However it's working when shifting to the Windows environment. I have dual operating systems on my machine.

Here are outputs of a few commands:

```
lshw -C Network:  
*-network UNCLAIMED  
description: Network controller  
product: BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n  
vendor: Broadcom Corporation  
physical id: 0  
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0  
version: 00  
width: 64 bits  
clock: 33MHz  
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list  
configuration: latency=0  
resources: memory:f7e00000-f7e03fff  

*-network  
description: Ethernet interface  
product: NetXtreme BCM5761 Gigabit Ethernet PCIe  
vendor: Broadcom Corporation  
physical id: 0  
bus info: pci@0000:0c:00.0  
logical name: eth0  
version: 10  
serial: b8:ca:3a:c4:3f:dd  
capacity: 1Gbit/s  
width: 64 bits  
clock: 33MHz  
capabilities: pm vpd msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt   10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation  
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=tg3 driverversion=3.123   firmware=5761-v3.80 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair  
resources: irq:44 memory:f7c10000-f7c1ffff memory:f7c00000-f7c0ffff  


Output of:  
rfkill list all:  
0: hci0: Bluetooth  
Soft blocked: no  
Hard blocked: no  

Output of:  
ifconfig  
eth0  
Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr b8:ca:3a:c4:3f:dd  
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1  
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  
Interrupt:18  
lo  
Link encap:Local Loopback  
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0  
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host  
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1  
RX packets:6446 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0  
TX packets:6446 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0  
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000  
RX bytes:3821480 (3.8 MB) TX bytes:3821480 (3.8 MB)  

Output for:  
lspci -nn | grep 0280  
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43228 802.11a/b/g/n   [14e4:4359]  

output for  
cat /etc/network/interfaces  
auto lo  
iface lo inet loopback
```

How do I sort out this issue?

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless device from: lspci -nn -d 14e4:

Answer (score 1):

Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo modprobe wl
```

Detach the ethernet and your wireless should be working.

Comment: Output of: **sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source**  Reading package lists.... Done
Building dependency tree  <br/> 
Reading state information... Done  <br/> 
E: unable to locate package linux-headers-generic  <br/>

Comment: linux-headers-generic is required as a dependency of bcmwl-kernel-source. What kernel version are you running? From the terminal: uname -a

Comment: Output of: uname -a :Linux Ubuntu 3.5.0-23_generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu

Comment: I don't believe this is the most updated kernel version. I suggest you do: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade. Reboot and try again.

Comment: I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 couple of weeks before and sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade both are resulting many statement with failed to fetch ................             Just to inform you I do not have any internet connection available apart from this wifi..

Comment: If you have no internet connection at all, this will be extremely difficult and tedious. I urge you to beg a connection by ethernet for a few minutes from a friend.